# zedgraph custom auto scale - but with minimum (of Min), and minimum of Max)

Tags: c#, zedgraph, minimum, autoscaling

I use Zedgraph in order to plot, and I use `AxisChange();` in order to auto-scale my graph.

My problem : I'd like to always see 0 to 10 on Y scale even After I go down or UP (auto-scale) , but I'd like always keep this value showed.

Here is an example of what I have now :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIqZK.png]

Here a screen shot of what I'd like to change (I want always see 0 to 10) even I have no value...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3iQF.png]

## EDIT

Sorry I wasn't clear enough...
My goal is to have a graph that display AT least 0 to 10 in the Yaxis (always). but if the values goes down (0 to -100) or up (10 to 100), the graph auto scale the Y axis and show more values.
For example even I've the value oscillating around "100" during 2 mins, I want to see my scale 0 to 110.

I don't know if it's possible or not?

In fact as soon as I put :

```
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
```

The auto scale stop working ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry I'd like to put image in the post, but I've no reputation for the moment... thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can *manually* set  **'Y' axis** as follows,

```
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
        myPane.AxisChange();
        zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```

and if you want to reverse the scale set the 'IsReverse' property to 'True'

```
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = true;
```

Comment: Hi San, 
Thanks a lot for your reply, 
Here I'm : http://s6.postimg.org/9iczszpc1/Unnamed_QQ_Screenshot20130621142704.png
I've the right Y axis for the begening but when it's goes more than 10, the "auto axis change" don't want to ...?

Maybe you know why ? Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate :)

Comment: No sure Whether I've understood your statement correctly, but there is a Boolean property to set the Bounds of the data, Please check the following link: http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_GraphPane_IsBoundedRanges.htm