# How to resize the graphs/charts inside zedgraph control to be bigger? they are very small by default

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void PlotHistogram(int[] values, string title, string xLabel, string yLabel, GraphPane graphPane, Color barColor)
        {
            GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
            pane.CurveList.Clear();

            // Convert int[] values to double[]
            double[] doubleValues = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => (double)x);

            // Add histogram bar graph
            BarItem barItem = graphPane.AddBar(title, null, doubleValues, barColor);
            barItem.Bar.Border.IsVisible = false;

            // Customize graph appearance
            graphPane.Title.Text = title;
            graphPane.XAxis.Title.Text = xLabel;
            graphPane.YAxis.Title.Text = yLabel;
            graphPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightGray, 45.0f);
            graphPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255), 45.0f);

            // Adjust the size of the graph to fit the control size
            graphPane.AxisChange();
            graphPane.AxisChange();

            // Calculate the desired size based on the control size
            int controlWidth = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Width;
            int controlHeight = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Height;
            int graphWidth = (int)((int)controlWidth - graphPane.Margin.Left - graphPane.Margin.Right);
            int graphHeight = (int)((int)controlHeight - graphPane.Margin.Top - graphPane.Margin.Bottom);

            // Set the size of the graph pane
            graphPane.Rect = new RectangleF(graphPane.Margin.Left, graphPane.Margin.Top, graphWidth, graphHeight);

            // Execute on the UI thread
            zedGraphControl1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
                
            });
        }
```

I tried this part to resize but it didn't change anything:

```
// Adjust the size of the graph to fit the control size
            graphPane.AxisChange();
            graphPane.AxisChange();

            // Calculate the desired size based on the control size
            int controlWidth = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Width;
            int controlHeight = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Height;
            int graphWidth = (int)((int)controlWidth - graphPane.Margin.Left - graphPane.Margin.Right);
            int graphHeight = (int)((int)controlHeight - graphPane.Margin.Top - graphPane.Margin.Bottom);

            // Set the size of the graph pane
            graphPane.Rect = new RectangleF(graphPane.Margin.Left, graphPane.Margin.Top, graphWidth, graphHeight);
```

this screenshot is at runtime while the application is running , the graphs/charts are very small:

[image: small graphs by default]

but if while it's running I'm dragging the mouse making rectangle around this graphs in the zedgraph control they will get resize as I wanted but I don't want to use the mouse for that I want it to be changed resize already in the code:

this is how it should be:

[image: resized graphs. this is how i want it to be or any other resized size to be reasonable logic to be able to see it more clear. the default is very very small.]

What i tried. in the form1 constructor changing the autosize to be false:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Controls.Add(this.zedGraphControl1);
            zedGraphControl1.Size = new Size(this.Width - 20, 300);
            zedGraphControl1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - zedGraphControl1.Width) / 2;
            zedGraphControl1.Top = this.Bottom - zedGraphControl1.Height - 20;
            zedGraphControl1.AutoSize = false;
            zedGraphControl1.BringToFront();
        }
```

then in the method PlitHistogram changed it a bit but still the chart is very small.

```
private void PlotHistogram(int[] values, string title, string xLabel, string yLabel, GraphPane graphPane, Color barColor)
        {
            graphPane.CurveList.Clear();

            // Convert int[] values to double[]
            double[] doubleValues = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => (double)x);

            // Add histogram bar graph
            BarItem barItem = graphPane.AddBar(title, null, doubleValues, barColor);
            barItem.Bar.Border.IsVisible = false;

            // Customize graph appearance
            graphPane.Title.Text = title;
            graphPane.XAxis.Title.Text = xLabel;
            graphPane.YAxis.Title.Text = yLabel;
            graphPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightGray, 45.0f);
            graphPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255), 45.0f);

            // Calculate the desired size based on the control size
            int controlWidth = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Width;
            int controlHeight = zedGraphControl1.ClientSize.Height;
            int graphWidth = (int)((int)controlWidth - graphPane.Margin.Left - graphPane.Margin.Right);
            int graphHeight = (int)((int)controlHeight - graphPane.Margin.Top - graphPane.Margin.Bottom);

            // Set the size of the graph pane
            graphPane.Rect = new RectangleF(graphPane.Rect.Location, new SizeF(graphWidth, graphHeight));

            // Refresh the control to update the graph size
            zedGraphControl1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
            zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
            });
        }
```

Comment: You are using autoscale.  The first point in the top screen shot has a point that is at 120 so the autoscale  is adjusting to view this point.  It looks like the scaling is keeping the height and width proportional.  So the same scaling factor is being applied to the height and width.

Comment: @jdweng I tried to set the autosize to false in the form1 constructor and changed a bit the method PlotHistogarm but still the chart is very small.   eidted my question with what I tried.

Comment: It is the first point at 120 that is giving the issue.  If you skip the first point everything will be ok. Or set x and y axis like at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224944/zedgraph-custom-auto-scale-but-with-minimum-of-min-and-minimum-of-max